# How to make simultaneous inference from two networks in one tensorflow graph?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I try to combine two different tensorflow networks (from object detection API zoo) in one graph and get simultaneous inference (output).
To do this, I load these two networks into one graph with different tensor name prefixes:

```
PATH_TO_FROZEN_GRAPH =  'frozen_graph1.pb'
PATH_TO_FROZEN_GRAPH2 =  'frozen_graph2.pb'

full_graph = tf.Graph()
with full_graph.as_default():
    od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_FROZEN_GRAPH, 'rb') as fid:
        serialized_graph = fid.read()
        od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
        tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='graph1')

    od_graph_def2 = tf.GraphDef()
    with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_FROZEN_GRAPH2, 'rb') as fid:
        serialized_graph2 = fid.read()
        od_graph_def2.ParseFromString(serialized_graph2)
        tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def2, name='graph2')

    image_tensor1 = full_graph.get_tensor_by_name('graph1/image_tensor:0')
    image_tensor2 = full_graph.get_tensor_by_name('graph2/image_tensor:0')

with full_graph.as_default():
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            image = Image.open(image_path)
            image = load_image_into_numpy_array(image)
            otput_dict = sess.run([full_graph.get_tensor_by_name('graph1/num_detections:0'), 
          full_graph.get_tensor_by_name('graph2/num_detections:0')], 
                                  feed_dict={image_tensor1: 
                                            np.expand_dims(image, 0), 
                                            image_tensor2: 
                                            np.expand_dims(image, 0)})
```

When I try to get output for the tensors of the same network, everything works:

```
sess.run([full_graph.get_tensor_by_name('graph1/num_detections:0'), 
          full_graph.get_tensor_by_name('graph1/num_detections:0')], 
                                  feed_dict={image_tensor1: 
                                            np.expand_dims(image, 0), 
                                            image_tensor2: 
                                            np.expand_dims(image, 0)})
```

But when I try to get the values of tensors from two different networks:

```
sess.run([full_graph.get_tensor_by_name('graph1/num_detections:0'), 
          full_graph.get_tensor_by_name('graph2/num_detections:0')], 
                                  feed_dict={image_tensor1: 
                                            np.expand_dims(image, 0), 
                                            image_tensor2: 
                                            np.expand_dims(image, 0)})
```

I get error:

```
Invalid loop structure: Loop "Preprocessor/map/while/while_context" has 
more than one LoopCond node: {{node graph2/Preprocessor/map/while/LoopCond}}
and {{node graph1/Preprocessor/map/while/LoopCond}}. 
This is an internal bug, please file a bug report with 
instructions on how to reproduce the error.
```

How can we separate these LoopCond nodes to get tensors from two different networks?